# ruby mongo can not find meteor generated _id

Tags: ruby, mongodb, meteor, mongoid

I have a ruby-sinatra application using mongoid 6.3 talking to a meteor database. Documents that are inserted from Meteor(index is a string) are fine accessing with either Mongoid or dropping into ruby::Mongo with no problem.

Documents inserted via ruby which generate an `ObjectId` for the `_id` field are valid in Meteor and Mongoid. However, when I want to drop down to the ruby mongo driver, none of the documents added via Mongoid are findable using the string value using `ruby::mongo`.

If I attempt to use ObjectId, mongo driver complains with: NoMethodError - undefined method `ObjectId' for #.

How do I either use `ruby::mongo` to find the document generated by ruby or generate an index in mongoid ActiveRecord that is usable by `ruby::mongo`?

Comment: I think you'll find that actually the "reverse", where Mongoid expects the `_id` to contain an `ObjectId` value and in fact it's a "string". If by *"drop down to the ruby driver[sic]"* you mean wrapping the value with `ObjectId` ( i.e `ObjectId(""Jjwjg6gouWLXhMGKW")` ) then that should be the same inherent "casting" problem you should be seeing in Mongoid ( if you did not tell your class that `_id` is a `string` ).

Comment: Basically the decision here is 1. Tell Meteor to use `ObjectId` 2. Tell Mongoid to use values like those created from meteor's [`Random`](https://docs.meteor.com/packages/random.html) package. It depends on which actually suits you best.

Comment: @Neil Lunn How do I tell Mongoid to use the random package?

Comment: Mongoid is creating the ObjectId keys. Meteor handles it, however, I need to do some things in Ruby: Mongo and it will not find them. I have tried both strings and ObjectId.

It seems odd that the low-level driver mongo that MOngoid uses will not read the same document it created.  I did a batch insert with mongo and it can not read the documents I inserted.

I have tried :
share_files.find(_id: ObjectId("5ad1723e77eacf6757605d1d"))
and
share_files.find(_id: '5ad1723e77eacf6757605d1d')
first one gives error  second one does not find anyting.

Comment: You really do have a few concepts messed around in your understanding, and you are in fact asking "multiple questions" though that may have not been your original intent. If you can keep the question to "How do I query a Mongoid Document from the Core Ruby Driver?", and simply show what you did to create and how you are trying to query, then we can point you in the right direction. But as for the rest, it actually works out to be "several" questions, and the format here is **one question** at a time. Keep in mind that most of those "several questions" have actually been answered before.